# How to fix patch 400 bad request after I made changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, axios

I am using react as front end and spring as backend. When I tried to patch json format using post man it works, I can update data by postman which means backend works. But when I use front end to update data it did not work.

editprofile.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import MemberService from "../../actions/MemberService";
import AuthenticationService from "./AuthenticationService";
import { updateUser } from "../../actions/sercurityActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import classnames from "classnames";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateProjectTask } from "../../actions/backlogActions";

class EditProfile extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
    
        this.state = {
          user:[],
          id: "",
          userName: "",
          password: "",
          email: "",
          contact: "",
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.refreshUsers = this.refreshUsers.bind(this);
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshUsers();
    
      }
      refreshUsers() {
        let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName();
        MemberService.retriveUserByName(username).
          then((Response) => {
            this.setState({ user: Response.data });
          });
      }
    
    
      onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      }
    
      onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName();
    
        const UpdateUser = {
          id:this.state.id,
          username: this.state.userName,
          password: this.state.password,
          contact: this.state.contact,
          email: this.state.email,
        };
    
        // console.log(UpdateProjectTask);
        this.props.updateUser(
            UpdateUser, this.props.history, username
        );
        console.log(this.state.id)
      }
    
      render() {
        const { errors } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className="add-PBI">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                  <h4 className="display-4 text-center">Update Profile</h4>
                  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                  <div className="form-group">
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        placeholder={this.state.user.id}
                        value={this.state.id}
                        name="id"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        placeholder={this.state.user.userName}
                        value={this.state.userName}
                        name="userName"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        placeholder={this.state.user.password}
                        value={this.state.password}
                        name="password"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        placeholder={this.state.user.email}
                        name="email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                      />
                    </div><div className="form-group">
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control form-control-lg"
                        placeholder={this.state.user.contact}
                        value={this.state.contact}
                        name="contact"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                      />
                    </div>
             <input
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

EditProfile.propTypes = {
    updateUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
  
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    errors: state.errors,
  });

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { updateUser }
  )(EditProfile);
```

userAction.js

```js
export const updateUser = (User,history,username) =>async dispatch =>{
  try {
      await axios.patch("/api/member/edit", User);
      history.push(`/profile/${username}`);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: {}
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    }
};
```

backend controller

```java
    @RequestMapping(value="/edit",method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result)
    {
        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap=mapValidationErrorService.MapValidationService(result);
        if(errorMap!=null) return errorMap;

        pmService.saveUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

here is the page pic.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZFV7.png)

and I can updata this kate with postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIPwF.png)

Comment: What do you see in your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel? It can show you exactly what data is being sent in the request

Comment: Ah, looks like a typo. You're using the key `username` in your `UpdateUser` object where it should be `userName` (capital "N"). Your server-side logs / response should have pointed this out to you though

Comment: thanks anyway! I figured it out yesterday on my own!